# Retrieving value from database and set dropdown selected item

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am currently having a hard time to retrieve the value from database columns and assign that value to dropdownlist.selecteditem.text. 
I have query like

```
SELECT [ProductName]+' '+ '('+[Category]+')' As  ProductNameCategory From Products
```

I want to assign the query result to drop down list.
like this

```
dropdownlist.selecteditem.text=ProductNameCategory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you call DisplayMember on DDL?

The below is syntax for a windows app. Where combobox is set up like a ddl. You need to tell what value to be binded.

```
        try //Try block for opening, querying and displaying pulled data
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("ConnString"); //Connection String
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Test_Names", sqlConn))
            {
                var table = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(table);           
                comboBox1.DataSource = t;       
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName"; //name of Column/DisplayName
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "Firstname"; //Name of Column/Value          
             }                                    
         }
        sqlConn.Close(); //Close Conn
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        //handle errors
        } //End Try Catch for SQL Operations
```

Comment: I have the required Data table.but drop down is populating  with the string of ProductNameCategory as the selected item .text, not the contents of the ProductNameCategory